# How to make the div occupy the available height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap framework, So while constructing a div if I give a height as 32em. It does perfectly fit in one phone, but when chosen the bigger size. The div does not occupy the remaining height in the bottom. *How to make it occupy the remaining height in the bottom if the phone is changed?*

Note that div is under the fluid-container and is the last div in that container. And code is something like this.

```
<style>
.box{
    height: 32em;
    background: grey;    
   }

</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row box"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: do you need to set container-fluid height to .box..? or screen height to .box..?

Comment: I did not override container-fluid. But that has several divs inside it. And this box is the last among those divs. Setting height: auto will only work when there is content right?

Comment: If you want to set screen height to the box, use this css height: 100vh;. Else if you need to use container-fliud height to box, use height: 100%; else I cannot understand what you expect by declaring height: 32em

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S3Gvf/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <!-- Rest of nav bar chopped from here -->
  </div>
  <div class="container fill">
    <div id="map"></div> <!-- This one wants to be 100% height -->
  </div>
</body>


#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, check the snippet below

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.small-box {
  width: 75%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="small-box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, would you like to explain a little about more about your answer

Comment: @gates Sure. The wrapper DIV `.container-fluid` has a fixed height of 32em. By defining `height: 100%` the inner block occupies the whole available heights defined by the heights of the parent block.

Comment: Same is applicable when the box is not only the div present inside the container-fluid. I mean like, there are other divs too present, but the last div is happen to be box. So in this case will the box occupy the remaining height?

Comment: @gates Then you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

One more solution is here

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;    
}
.container-fluid {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    display: table-cell;
    background: grey;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row box">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also find this solution in [myblog](http://antonysuthakarj.blogspot.com/2015/11/how-to-make-div-occupy-available-height.html)